# how to move obj to the top of list in c#

Tags: c#

I want to move some object where `obj.Coach.Id=xxx` in to the top of `List<obj>`, this is my solution, but I think it's not optimal, because it will Traversal at two times. Is there any good way to implement this?

```cs
    List<AppointmentDTO> res = await this.appointmentService.GetCanReserve(coachId, date);

    var id =  HttpContext.User.FindFirst("id")?.Value;
    if (id is not null)
    {
        var temp= res.Where(r => r.Coach.Id == id).ToList();

        res = res.Where(r => r.Coach.Id != id).ToList();

        res.InsertRange(0,temp);
    }
```

Comment: how about `Remove(temp)` and then [InsertAt(0, temp)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Read the documentation for `List<T>`, particularly the `Insert` and `Remove` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OrderBy and ThenBy to order your results. ie:

```
var ordered = res.OrderBy(r => r.Coach_id == id?0:1)
                 .ThenBy(r => r.Coach_id)
                 .ToList();
```